# Is there an optimization method with these characteristics?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, convex-optimization

I have been looking at tons of papers recently, however I'm not expert in the topic. I am looking for a method/algorithm that has all (or many) of these properties:

- derivative-free (non gradient based)
- Parallelisable
- can cope with multiple local extrema & discontinuous objective function

If possible it should also be simple to implement and asynchronous, but these are extra. Is there any method having all of the 3 above? I looked at GPS, GSS, golden section, Fibonacci, hooke & Jeeve's and Nelder-Mead's methods but I found nothing.

Comment: Simulated annealing is a global optimization procedure.

Comment: @Wuestenfux I am quite ignorant. Does that mean that it satisfied those 3 properties?

Comment: Its non-gradient based and fulfills part 3. You can run the algorithm in parallel by letting each thread start with a different starting point (seed).

Comment: @Wuestenfux great! Would you say it is simple to implement?

Comment: Of course, it is. In each step, the algorithm needs to draw a random number between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Wuestenfux  If you can briefly describe the method and write what you wrote here, I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a universe of solutions, there is an energy function $E$ on the set of solutions, and each solution $x$ has a neighborhood $N(x)$ consisting of all solutions which are obtained from $x$ by small pertubations.

Start from high temperature $t=T_\max$ and pick a solution $x$ at random.

In each step, decrease the temperature say by 1%, i.e., $t\leftarrow t*0.99$.
Pick a solution $y\in N(x)$ at random. If $E(y)>E(x)$, then $y<\leftarrow x$ and resume with $y$ by setting $x\leftarrow y$. (So far, this looks like hill climbing or steepest ascent.) Otherwise, a random number $r\in[0,1]$ is drawn. If $r <\exp((E(y)-E(x))/T)$, then $y\leftarrow x$. (This allows to escape from local optima.) Otherwise, do not change $x$. Now resume.

Exit if a given number of iterations is reached or the temperature is low enough.

When the temperature is high, it is easy to escape from local optima since the Boltzmann factor $\exp((E(y)-E(x))/T)$ is close to 1. However, when the temperature is low, the Boltzmann factor is close to 0 and so the probability test will hardly be successful.

Theoretically, under mild assumptions (infinite cooling plan), the algorithm is guaranteed to reach the global optimum. I hope it helps.

Comment: thank you it helps a lot! How would you parallelize this again? If you could just expand a little on that, that would be perfect thanks

Comment: You could make several runs in parallel which start from different starting points (solutions).

Comment: is there a chance that in this way you could take into account certain neighbouring points more than once?

Comment: Suppose the solution $x$ cannot be changed in one step (uphill and downhill move do not work; i.e. $E(y)<E(x)$ and probabilistic test fails), the algorithm resumes with $x$ and picks another solution in the neighborhood of $x$. You could exclude solutions $y\in N(x)$ which have already been picked. If there is no change to improve the solution $x$, then stop prematurely.